# Where is virtual host configuration for apache httpd server

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

I can access the apache httpd configuration file in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, where would the virtual hosts configuration be?

P.S: there is no /etc/apache2/ folder.

Answer (score 3):

Virtual hosts are a completely regular part of the Apache httpd configuration, so they can be placed in the main `httpd.conf` file, next to all other settings.

If you want them to be in a separate file, you can do that too – as long as you import that file using the `Include` command in the main configuration.

For example, the standard httpd.conf has a line:

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

By default it is commented out (prefixed with `#`), so first remove the comment sign, then you'll be able to use `/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` if you like.